# Azure CLI: Passing multiple protocol values while creating NSG rule

Tags: azure, azure-cli

How to pass multiple protocol values using Azure CLI while creating nsg rule.

RG="Test-RG"

az network nsg create --name "${RG}-nsg" --location "eastus" -g $RG

az network nsg rule create -g ${RG} --nsg-name "${RG}-nsg" -n ${RG}-nsg-rule1 --priority 100 
--source-address-prefixes '*' --source-port-ranges '*' --destination-address-prefixes '*' 

--destination-port-ranges '*' --access Allow **--protocol Tcp** --description "Allowing All Traffic"

For protocol parameter I am trying to pass multiple values like Icmp Udp

--protocol {Tcp,Icmp}

--protocol [Tcp, Icmp}

I have tried both ways not working

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSG rules allow these protocols `*, Ah, Esp, Icmp, Tcp, Udp` While creating NSG rule you can use only one protocols not multiple.

The parameter [protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/add-aznetworksecurityruleconfig?view=azps-9.7.1#-protocol) can accepts only string you cannot pass more than one protocol. You can use Wildcard character (*) to match all.